# How to Do Exercise numbering well in columns for Math?

Tags: math-mode

I want this layout:

[image]

I normally write mostly sections and subsections but I would like to deprecate the thing. 
I would like to know

- how you can adjust exercise numbers to have their own columns at left?
- how you can adjust exercise subnumbers (a, b, ...) have on another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like nested `enumerate` - environments?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item % Don't use an empty line here
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]

\item Find the solution of ...

  \blindtext

\item Find something different

  \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]